# How to ask if someone will contact A instead of requesting that they actually contact A?

Tags: word-choice, questions, politeness, formal-language

A man said me we should contact to A.
And I thought does he want to contact with A by himself?
So I asked :

> Will you contact with him?

I didn't want to say 'So can you contact?' I just want to say 'So you will gonna contact?'.

I mean... I didn't request him to contact A. Just I wanted to know whether he wanted to contact to A by himself or wanted me contacting to A.

I think 'will you' is not appropriate to use in this case. But also I think 'gonna' is not polite.

So in this case, what word should I use?

Comment: Note that *contact* is a transitive verb: we say *contact [somebody]*, not *contact with [somebody]* or *contact to [somebody]*.

Comment: "So are you going to contact him, or do you want me to?"

Comment: Welcome to ELL - I've edited your question for you and deleted the other post. The mobile app is a little different, but it should have the same basic functionality as the web site, including being able to delete your posts. I don't have it installed though, so maybe someone else could help you find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you might express this:

> Will you contact him, or shall I?
>   Are you going to contact him, or do you want me to?
>   Do you want to contact him, or should I?
>   Which of us should contact him, you or me? —*but purists would insist on* I *rather than* me
>   Who's going to contact him, you or me?

and so forth. There's nothing "impolite" about the *BE going to* construction, but the use of eye-dialect spellings like *gonna* suggests, either literally or ironically, substandard usage.